# while loop not updating i after each iteration

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
    while (var<10)  
        {

        String line=keyboard.nextLine();
        input = line.charAt(0);

        game.makeGuess(input);
        game.getDisguisedWord();
        game.isFound();
        System.out.println(game.getDisguisedWord());
        System.out.println(game);
        System.out.println(game.getWrong());
        int i=0;
        i++;
        if (var<i+game.getDisguisedWord().length()-1)
            System.out.print("Guess #" + game.guessCount()+": ");
        var=game.getWrong();
        if (game.isFound())
            var=10;
    }
```

not sure what's wrong, but if I print out i, it just stays at 1. I need to do this in order to get something to stop printing :(

Comment: put 'int i=0;' out of the while loop.

Comment: What does `game.getWrong()` returns ? Where do you change the value of `var` ? Why are you initializing `int i=0;` inside the loop ?

Answer (score 2):

`int i=0` is the error. It initialises i to 0 in every iteration, thus your i value stays at 1 after `i++` in the next step. To initialize it only once, put it outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing i in every iteration.

```
int i = 0;
```

has to be outside of the loop body, before the loop. It would also make sense to put

```
String line = keyboard.nextLine();
```

outside of the loop body as well. 'line' doesn't need to be initialized in every iteration either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
int i = 0;
```

above the

```
    while (var<10)  
        {
```

This is because you are calling the 'i' variable each time it loops, then using i++, it will always be '1'. Thus will not save it for the next loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `i` will be treated as a local variable, and every time the loop completes one iteration, `i` will be destroyed.

In the next iteration, `i` will be created and initialized by 0. You need to initialize this variable outside of your while loop.